# Change Materialize theme colors from CDN

Tags: css, materialize

I am using Materialize on a project, and I ***MUST*** load Materialize by using the CDN links.
So in my project headers, I have :

```
<!-- Compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/css/materialize.min.css">

<!-- Compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/materialize/1.0.0/js/materialize.min.js"></script>
```

I now want to change the project theme colors.

I know that by using SASS, I could use a `_variables.sass` file somewhere to change the default values, but since it's loaded from the CDN I can't do it.

What is the proper way to do that while loading Materialize from its CDN?

**I tried:**

- Setting a new variable in my project main CSS file:

```
$primary-color: red;
$primary-color-light: lighten($primary-color, 15%) !important;
$primary-color-dark: darken($primary-color, 15%) !important;
```

***Not working.***

- Setting this variable to `!important`:

```
$primary-color: red !important;
$primary-color-light: lighten($primary-color, 15%) !important;
$primary-color-dark: darken($primary-color, 15%) !important;
```

***Not working.***

Answer (score 0):

So two points here:

**1)** Since that CDN file is coming as compiled CSS and not SASS, the SASS variables are not available to edit, so you're not going to actually overwrite anything with your own SASS files.

**2)** By accessing this CSS file, you should have all of their color classes already available to use (eg: `<div class="card-panel teal lighten-2">`). From my view this is the intended way to use this library with your given setup, so you can edit your HTML elements' classes throughout your project to your heart's content.

https://materializecss.com/color.html